# Assigning "$@" to a variable in Bash and preserving escaping

Tags: bash, escaping, arguments, printf

If I save the following script as 'args.bash' and run `bash args.bash -a 'foo bar'`

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    set -x
    which "$@"

    local args="$@"
    which "$args"
    which $args

    local args=$(printf " %q" "$@")
    which "$args"
    which $args
}
main "$@"
```

I'm surprised to see that these print different results. The first one prints:

```
which -a 'foo bar'
```

Which I expect! It groups the arguments properly.

The rest of them print, in order:

```
which '-a foo bar'
which -a foo bar
which ' -a foo\ bar'
which -a 'foo\' bar
```

Which are all incorrect to one degree or another. How can I assign `"$@"` to a variable, and get it to echo the same output as the first command?

Comment: You cannot store arbitrary commands/arguments in a string and keep correct quoting/etc. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion of this. You need to use an array.

Comment: Well -- he's using `printf %q`, which changes things a bit, but an array is still the Right Thing.

Comment: `printf %q` was the only thing I knew to try - open to any other suggestions.

Comment: `$@` has special behavior precisely *because* ordinary parameters can't keep arguments distinct in a single string (and arrays aren't in POSIX, whereas `$@` is).

Answer (score 3):

Use an array variable, not a scalar:

```
items=( "$@" )
which -a "${items[@]}"
```

However, if you **must** use a scalar<sub>[1]</sub>, you had the right approach with `printf '%q '`; note, however, that `printf %q` creates a string which will evaluate back to itself *when run through the full parser* (thus requiring `eval` or an equivalent to ensure that the full parser is invoked):

```
printf -v items_str '%q ' "$@"
eval "which -a $items_str"
```

---

<sub>[1]</sub> The number of circumstances where one has bash extensions such as `printf -v` and `%q` but can't use an array is limited, but they do exist; particularly, passing values to a subprocess through the environment comes to mind. However, in the bulk of cases where arrays are inappropriate, I'd expect either using a series of distinct environment variables (one per value), or passing a NUL-delimited stream (as created by `printf '%s\n' "$@"`) to be more appropriate, even if (as for the environment) it might need to be escaped (for instance, via base64-encoding).

Comment: Ugh, so you have to use the eval there?

Comment: If you don't want to do the right thing and use an array, yes.

Comment: (Do go read through FAQ 50, as linked in comments on the question, to grok *why* this is necessary).

Comment: Keep in mind that `%q` and the `-v` are both `bash` extensions to `printf`, so you may as well use the array.

Comment: @chepner, indeed; the case where an array can't be used would be that where we're actually exporting this list through the environment. (In other cases, such as over a serial line, NUL-delimited form would be better). Though even sending it through the environment, I might use a different approach myself (base64-encoding a NUL-delimited stream? Multiple, separate environment variables?) if there were any possible way the components or communication protocol might be untrusted.

Comment: True; I thought of that after I commented, and couldn't decide if it was worth editing the comment to mention. Worth having on record, though.

Comment: Amended an appropriate note.